# Проблема с суммой значений

Tags: jquery, html5

```js
$(function() {
  $(".test").click(function(){
    var a=$("#l_inpt_1").val();
    var b=$("#l_inpt_2").val();
    var c=$("#l_inpt_3").val();
    var sumS=(a+b+c)/3;
    $(".midle_g p").append(sumS);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" placeholder="Число 1" id="l_inpt_1">
<input type="text" placeholder="Число 1" id="l_inpt_2">
<input type="text" placeholder="Число 1" id="l_inpt_3">
<button class="test">Очистити поля</button>
<div class="midle_g">
   <p></p>
</div>
```

У нас есть 3 инпута допустим в них мы впишем числа 1,2,3 по нажатию на кнопку у нас должно найти среднее значения (1+2+3)/3=2, но проблема в том что сума отображает как 123 а не 6!Как исправить!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас поля были добавлены не числами, а текстом. `ParseFloat` превращает текст в число

```js
$(function() {
  $(".test").click(function(){
    var a = parseFloat($("#l_inpt_1").val());
    var b = parseFloat($("#l_inpt_2").val());
    var c = parseFloat($("#l_inpt_3").val());
    var sumS = (a+b+c)/3;
    $(".midle_g p").append(sumS);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" placeholder="Число 1" id="l_inpt_1">
<input type="text" placeholder="Число 1" id="l_inpt_2">
<input type="text" placeholder="Число 1" id="l_inpt_3">
<button class="test">Очистити поля</button>
<div class="midle_g">
   <p></p>
</div>
```

Comment: В jquery код не работает!

Comment: @GenralSite, в смысле? У меня всё работает

Comment: заменил свой код на вас , при нажатие на кнопку не работает!

Comment: @GenralSite, тогда почему тут пример кода работает? Вы указали ссылку на библиотеку?

Comment: Да указал другие функции работают на ура , а ета не хочет!

Comment: @GenralSite, ответ у меня работает. Нажмите: Выполнить код и пример будет рабочий. Я не знаю, что у вас там не работает

Comment: спасибо большое, допустил ошибку в коде уже все работает!